# Content blocks in Adobe Campaign

Tags: adobe-campaign-classic

I'm working on Adobe Campaign Developer.

I'm facing some issue at content block creation.

I need to check the Date that it is:

- If the date is equal to today need to show  'Pay today'
- need to check the date from the fields the field is like
  (28,11/23/2023)
- need the code in script type

  <%
  var myDate, myFormatDate;
  var date_str = context.SERVICE.custom_field_5;
  var t = date_str.split(",");
  myDate = new Date(t[3]);
  myFormatDate = formatDate(myDate, "%B %D");
  %>
  <%= myFormatDate %>